# Wide dummies to long factor with expansion of rows

Tags: r

Many resources exist on transforming data from wide to long and visa versa. There's a little twist here, but if I've missed any existing answer please let me know.

The twist is that I have some rows indicated by multiple flags (dummy variables). I need to not only go from wide to long, but to simultaneously make copies of rows with multiple flags. In addition, while there is other miscellaneous data, there is no unique ID, thus no "timevar" or "idvar".

Example:

```
ds <- data.frame(other_data=c(1,2,3),flag_a = c(1,0,0), flag_b=c(0,1,0), flag_c=c(1,0,1))
ds
```

> ```
>   other_data flag_a flag_b flag_c
> 1          1      1      0      1
> 2          2      0      1      0
> 3          3      0      0      1
> ```

```
desired_result <- data.frame(other_data=c(1,1,2,3), flag=c("a", "c","b","c"))
desired_result
```

> ```
>   other_data flag
> 1          1    a
> 2          1    c
> 3          2    b
> 4          3    c
> ```

Comment: I think other_data can serve as an id var..? `library(data.table); melt(setDT(ds), id = "other_data", variable.factor = FALSE)[value == 1, .(other_data, substr(variable, nchar(variable), nchar(variable)))]`

Comment: @Frank In the real data set other data is like 40 columns of heavily non-distinct data, like 4 level factors over hundreds of rows. Would that still work?

Comment: The only problem I might expect would be that you'd temporarily have an object with rows for all those zeroes, which might strain memory. With only hundreds of rows and 40 flags, I guess it'll be fine, though. Btw, not posting separately because it's just a (not-great) variation of MrFlick's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can reshape, filter, and transform with the tidyverse

```
library(tidyverse)
gather(ds, flag, present, flag_a:flag_c) %>% 
  filter(present>0) %>% 
  separate(flag, c("pre","flag")) %>% 
  select(-present, -pre)
```

Which results in ...

```
#   other_data flag
# 1          1    a
# 2          2    b
# 3          1    c
# 4          3    c
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless I misunderstood what you want, you can do this with `dplyr` and `tidyr::gather`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
res <- ds %>% gather("flag","value",-1) %>% 
              filter(value != 0) %>% 
              mutate(flag=sub("flag_","",flag)) %>% 
              select(-value)
##  other_data flag
##1          1    a
##2          2    b
##3          1    c
##4          3    c
```

We `gather` all columns except the first (i.e., `other_data`). We first `filter` to keep only those rows for which `value != 0`, then we extract the flag name from `flag` using `sub`. Finally, we remove the `value` column.

Comment: `gather()` comes from `tidyr`, not `dplyr`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `base R` option to get the output

```
data.frame(other_data = rep(ds[,1], rowSums(ds[-1]!=0)),
       flag = sub(".*_", "", names(ds)[-1][t(ds[-1]*col(ds[-1]))]))
#   other_data flag
#1          1    a
#2          1    c
#3          2    b
#4          3    c
```